# benchmark tools for linux

Tags: benchmark

I have developed a software with perl language based on the Spread Toolkit which is a network messages manager through the network(messages software through the network), now I have to stress my application and benchmark it, so being able to see the CPU and memory consumption, etc.

Could you recommend any benchmark tool for Linux? I have no idea about which software I could use. I can stress my app but don't know how to to see the system performance.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what exactly are you looking for. For trivial system load monitoring there is `top` and a more nifty `htop`.

Then there a dozens of specialized monitors for network, I/O, battery consumption...

If you are actually looking for performance holes in the software, you would need a profiler. For network software, the only free usable profile is oProfile (some commercial profilers support time-based profiling as well).

Here is a little bit about perl profiling (but I'm pretty sure that this doesn't capture idle-time) http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/25/profiling.html

Comment: I mainly need to stress an application which called spread toolkit to send messages through the network, any why I basically tail log files and send messages.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try [apache jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org).

I have no practical experience with this tool, but in official description of [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org):

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and
>   dynamic resources (files, Servlets, Perl scripts, Java Objects, Data
>   Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can be used to simulate a
>   heavy load on a server, network or object to test its strength or to
>   analyze overall performance under different load types. You can use it
>   to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your
>   server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.

Perhaps it isn't good solution but you could setup a CGI web service, and test your application with Jmeter like a web service stress test!?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Anthon It may not be a very complete answer, but it's an answer nonetheless (albeit phrased as a question).

Comment: Please don't just leave a link: explain what the tool you linked to does.